# os.path in python doesn't work correctly after remove USB flash

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I work on a music player from USB-flash on a Raspberry PI Zero with a LCD and control by MPD (Music Player Daemon). I would like to display on the LCD that there isn't USB stick plugged in and I don't know how.

I plug in the USB stick, it is automounted to `/media/sda1` for example. When MPD plays a song from USB (for example `/media/sda1/dir1/1.mp3`) and I remove USB stick, then `os.path.exists("/media/sda1/dir1/")` still returns `True`. Why? In fact, there is an empty `/media/sda1/` and nothing else.

After removing USB stick while playing a song, as far as I tested:

- `os.access("/media/sda1/dir1/", os.R_OK)` -> `True`
- `os.access("/media/sda1/dir1/", os.F_OK)` -> `True`
- `os.path.getsize("/media/sda1/dir1/")` -> `4096`
- `os.path.isdir("/media/sda1/dir1/")` -> `True`

Is `os.path()` like a cached result? I didn't test it with Python3, only 2.7.13